# Android Support V4 broken link in submodule directory

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I am using the datetime picker for android available at: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/datetimepicker

My IDE is IntelliJ but i do not have Gradle enabled for my project (lesson learned) so I added that repo as a submodule for my project, and added the module to the project. All seems fine, but there is a /libs/ file inside that datetimepicker directory that contains a link to android-support-v4, and a mouseover shows "broken link" as a consequence, the logcat shows that android.support.v4 does not exist. I have that .jar in my project main /libs/ dir and I use it without problems there. 
I would appreciate any help on that issue that is bothering me for the past one hour.

I attach a screenshot too.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems that the link was really broken, so for anyone else that faces the same problem, just copy the support library, and import it again, that solved the problems.